# Mutate vuex state object outside of store

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Suppose a store like this

```
...
state: {
    filters: {
        a: '',
        b: ''
    }
},
mutations: {
    updateFilters(state, newObject) {
        state.filters = newObject
    }
}
...
```

And a component like this

```
...
<input v-model='filters.a'></input>
...
computed: {
    filters: {
        get() {
            this.$store.state.filters
        }
        set(value) {
            this.$store.commit('updateFilters', value)
        }
    }
}
...
```

Everything works fine but I see a warning saying

> Error: "[vuex] do not mutate vuex store state outside mutation
> handlers."

So I'm obviously missing something

I don't understand how to handle this.
Can someone explain how to mutate a state object in a component?

I know, I can mutate every filters prop, but I have a LOT of filters in that object, so mutate every single prop is not the best solution in this case.

Comment: if you do `state.filters ={newObject}` you are getting the same warning?

Comment: Is ES6 Shorthand sintax

Comment: You can use a generic mutator which will have 2 arguments - the object key to mutate (your filter) and the value to be set.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your setter never gets called. The getter is used, but `a` is updated directly.

Here is one option:

```
<input :value="filters.a" @input="updateFilterA"></input>
...
computed: {
  filters() {
    return this.$store.state.filters /* or mapState */
  }
},
methods: {
  updateFilterA(value) {
    this.$store.commit("updateFilterA", value)
  }
}
```

And in the store:

```
mutations: {
  updateFilterA(state, newValue) {
    state.filters.a = newValue
  }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want a specific mutation for each filter, follow @IVOGELOV's suggestion from the comments and update the mutation to accept both the filter to update and the value.